# "NFC Service has stopped" dialog repeatedly popping up

Tags: android-11, nfc

Phone: Cubot KingKong 5 Pro
Android 11, Security Update July 5.

A couple of days ago the phone "crashed" and restarted itself. It does that from time to time, at worst it did it once per week or so, now less, like once in one or two months.

After it was back up, I've been getting a "Nfc Service has stopped" dialog, like every 30-60 seconds. If I close the dialog, a new one appears soon. It makes using the phone quite hard as there is constantly that dialog blocking the screen.

App Info says the culprit is "Nfc Service", go figure. I have already disabled it, but that dialog seems to come anyway. I don't use nor need NFC (as far as I know).

If I go to Android Settings -> Connected devices -> Connection preferences -> NFC, I see only "Advanced settings", and clicking on it does nothing. Does this mean NFC is already disabled?

As said, I am fine if NFC is completely disabled, as long as those irritating notes go away. Is there anything I can do, besides resetting the whole phone? I'd rather try to avoid it because I have some apps I have to backup & restore manually, like a VPN token software (it has to be set up again whenever I either change phone or reset the phone), Whatsapp and MapFactor navigator POIs.

Comment: It sounds like the hardware of the NFC antenna may not be recognized since it can't see the settings; the NFC settings page should have an on/off toggle.

Comment: My Ulefone has been doing this since yesterday, after I restarted it. Running Android 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with my Armor phone. I contacted the importer, and they replied that a bug in an online banking app (S-mobiili) was the culprit and that deleting it until they got it fixed would do the trick. And it did! Hope it fixes your problem too.

Comment: I mark this as the solution as while I can't confirm this was the actual issue in my case, I had the same online banking app installed at the time. I did end up resetting the whole phone to default settings and also removing many apps that I used to have. I haven't had the issue ever since.

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Unihertz Jelly 2, also with Android 11. I contacted the manufacturer, and they instructed me to install an OTA update available from their website (the System Update under Settings said that no update is available). After installing the update, the problem went away. I'm not entirely sure if it was a new version or just reinstalling the latest update. In any case, I was able to do it without having to reset my phone to factory settings, although I did do a backup beforehand just to be sure.

Some additional details: In my case, the NFC stopped working after the phone ran out of battery during normal usage. I similarly had popups every minute or so, and also the battery was draining extremely quickly (100% to 0% in around 5-6h even if I did nothing with the phone). After the update, both issues were fixed.

(Sorry if this is not helpful for your case, but hopefully someone else benefits from this.)